# Angular combining the same values from an array into a single object

Tags: arrays, angular, sorting

I have an array:

```
array = [{
    name: 'Camilla',
    date: '00.08.1990'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    date: '10.06.2022'
  },
  {
    name: 'Paul',
    date: '10.06.2022'
  }];
```

The html code:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of array">To be sorted: 
  <div style="border-style: solid">{{value.date}} - {{value.name}}</div>
</div>
```

I would like to have this result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtkKq.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need the concept of **GROUP BY**, group by date.

Iterate the `name` from the `names` array for each date group.

```
<div *ngFor="let value of groupedArray">
  To be sorted:
  <div style="border-style: solid">
    {{ value.date }} -
    <ng-container *ngFor="let name of value.names">
      {{ name }}
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can achieve this with [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for transforming the array into a new form.

```js
this.groupedArray = this.array.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let index = acc.findIndex((x) => cur.date == x.date);

  if (index > -1) {
    acc[index].names.push(cur.name);
  } else {
    acc.push({ date: cur.date, names: [cur.name] });
  }

  return acc;
}, [] as { date: string; names: string[] }[]);
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-reaqht?file=src/app/app.component.ts)